# Adding in values SET python

Tags: python

I start learning Python by myself, I googled around but I can not find the solution,

This is practice of lottery code and I would like to ask User couple of question. It is still practicing.

I try to build "add_players()" part.

So, My code is right now

```
user_players = set()

lottery_numbers = {13, 21, 22, 5, 8}

def menu():
    user_input = input("ADD,SHOW,ROLL or QUIT  ")
    user_input=user_input.upper()

    while user_input != 'QUIT':
        if user_input == 'ADD':
            add_players()
        #elif user_input == 'SHOW':
        #   show_players()
        elif user_input == 'ROLL':
            roll()
        else:
            print('Done bye')
        user_input = input("ADD,SHOW,ROLL or QUIT ")


def add_players():
    name_input = input('Name?: ')
    numbers_input = int(input('number?: '))

    new_users = user_players.add(
        {
            'name': name_input,
            'numbers': numbers_input
        }
    )
def roll():
    for i in new_users:
        Matched1 = i['numbers'].intersection(lottery_numbers)
        print("{} matched {} ".format(i['name'], Matched1))

menu()
```

So when a user chose "ADD",

I would like to add values to my SET

which is this logic

```
def add_players():
        name_input = input('Name?: ')
        numbers_input = int(input('number?: '))

        new_users = user_players.add(
            {
                'name': name_input,
                'numbers': numbers_input
            }
        )
```

for example,

John
1,2,3,4,5

I know I should use add function, but

I am missing this part

```
 new_users = user_players.add(
                {
                    'name': name_input,
                    'numbers': numbers_input
                }
            )
```

How can I change my code to add players and their numbers? so when user choose "ROLL", It shows like "John matched 5"

Comment: What do you mean by "I am missing this part"? What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{
    'name': name_input,
    'numbers': numbers_input
}
```

cannot be added to a set since a dict is not hashable. Try using a data structure that is hashable like tuple to suit your case.

For example,

```
new_users = user_players.add((name_input, numbers_input))
```

Also for your roll function, you refer to `new_users` which aren't accessible in the function. `new_users` you declared in `add_players` function only lives inside that function. So you'd want to declare it else where, like just below `user_players` on the top and add to it in the functions as you go.